# PHP - mkdir() works manually but not when executed by cron

Tags: php, cron, permissions, mkdir

I need to create a daily directory (/YYYYMMDD). I am using mkdir() function. It works fine when i run it manually, but when it is executed by cron, it is not able to create the directory.

I think the problem is about permissions, but I even tried modifying the directory to 777 and still not working.

Here is how I am using mkdir():

```
if (!file_exists($auxfile)) {
    if (!@mkdir($auxfile, 0777, true)) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo $error['message'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember, your cron job does not run in the same directory or using the same privilages as when you using your account do this from the terminal or from a website

Comment: If you have a problem, putting the `@` error silencer on the script with the problem is rather self defeating. Remove it and see what the error actually is, then you may be able to solve it

Comment: Or do you get an error from the `echo $error['message'];`

Comment: the directory in which you are trying to `mkdir` must have permissions for a user running the script from cron

Comment: The thing here is that it has been working for a long time, and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Well then, maybe someone changed the permissions, and/or some other factor? These things don't just stop working for no reason. But if you haven't changed the actual code, then we're unlikely to be able to see the problem by simply looking at that code. Again though, as pointed out above you really ought to improve the error handling and then you might get more useful info.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it old-skool by example in DirectAdmin. You need to make sure to use the home path. E.g. `mkdir('/home/DOMAIN.COM/public_html/results/'.$auxfile);`